# How to disable and re-enable video card and keyboard drivers on Windows as part of program testing?

Tags: windows

For my game I want to give the user full control. I am writing a hangman game where the user has the option of pressing the 'X' key on the keyboard to disable the keyboard driver completely, and 'G' to disable the graphics card.

You can re-enable by left-clicking the screen, but thus far I have found no ways of doing this, or tutorials, not even questions!

Can someone point me in the direction here? Thanks.

Comment: Your game will segfault on the next driver call, unless you bloat up each method to check if the card still exists (based on your other question I'm assuming you're not using DirectX or OpenGL). It's like trying to put a check in your game for a power outage, you can't really do anything about it.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. This isn't directly related to game development and you'd probably get a better answer at superuser.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

As this is for testing, I'd suggest getting the tester to do it manually through device manager in the windows control panel. The tester would have to disable and enable them an awful lot before it would become worthwhile programming some shortcuts.

Alternatively instead of disabling them at that level just program the game to have a couple of booleans that you adjust in the appropriate places which control rendering and input.

P.S. Why do you want to test this? I can't think of any sensible situation where this would happen when playing a game.

Comment: Your answer is fuzzy to me in some areas, specifically the "tester" part.